# Laravel 5.1 How to sort collection using lists() method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have two questions/help to fix here:

1. How to reduce redundancy in this line of code `$this->all()->lists('name', 'id')->all()`
2. How to call mutator by using `orderBy` method.

helper.php

```
if (! function_exists('withEmpty')) {

    function withEmpty($selectList, $emptyLabel = '')
    {
        return array('' => $emptyLabel) + $selectList;
    }
}
```

Agent.php (model)

```
public function getNameAttribute($value){
    return $this->lname.', '.$this->fname.' '.$this->mname;
  }

public function listAgents($emptyLabel = '--Select Agent--'){

    return withEmpty($this->all()->lists('name', 'id')->all(), $emptyLabel);


  }
```

Answer (score 4):

**1.** Change this:

```
$this->all()->lists('name', 'id')->all()
```

To:

```
$this->all()->lists('name', id)
```

**2.** You can't do that. Use [`sortBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortby) and [`sortByDesc()`](http://sortByDesc()) collection methods with a closure instead:

```
->sortBy(function($i) {
    return $i->name;
});
```

Comment: thanks, but in 'pluck', laravel still  throwing exception 'Column not found: 1054 Champ 'name''.

Comment: @jp.palubs oh, you're on 5.1. In this case, use `lists()` as I've shown in updated answer.

Comment: still got error, but when I changed 'name' to 'lname' it worked (because its the field name in the table). but when i try just 'name' mutator it doesnt. should I try other way to call that 'name' or combine two fields in my code?

Comment: @jp.palubs since name is an accessor, do this `all()->lists('name', 'id')`. For a column, you don't need to execute the query first. So, when you do `all()->listst()`, you're using collection method and not Eloquent builder method.

Comment: now it throws "Trying to get property of non-object", is this because of I put the code inside the model?

Comment: @jp.palubs I don't think this error is related to the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck)** and **[sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortby)** method and then apply a closure

```
$this->pluck('name', 'id')->sortBy(function($el) {
    return $el->name;
});
```